# Wrap group of XML nodes

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Im working with PHP5, and I need to transform XML in the following form:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>          
    </item>
</list>
```

Into something like this:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
    </item>
</list>
```

As you can see above I need to add a wrapper node to any 'item' nodes that are not wrapped by the 'list' node already.

What are possible solutions for transforming source xml to the target xml?

**UPDATED:**

Note 1: Any single or group of `<item>` nodes needs to be wrapped by a `<list>` node if its not wrapped already.

Note 2: Order of the content needs to be maintained.

Note 3:
If there are `<item>` nodes before and after `<anotherNode>`.
It should transform this:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>          
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <item label="c">some text</item>
        <item label="d">some text</item>          
    </item>
</list>
```

into this:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>          
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="c">some text</item>
            <item label="d">some text</item>
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
    </item>
</list>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short solution in the spirit of XSLT.

Comment: @Benjamin-Ortuzar: Have you forgotten to accept an answer? Still not fully satisfied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item/item[1]">
  <list>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
    select=".| following-sibling::item"/>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item/item[not(position()=1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </item>
</list>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<list>
   <item label="(1)">some text</item>
   <item label="(2)">
      <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
      <list>
         <item label="a">some text</item>
         <item label="b">some text</item>
      </list>
   </item>
</list>
```

**Do note**:

1. The use and overriding of the *Identity rule*.
2. The suppression of certain elements.
3. The processing of certain elements using a different *mode*.

**Update**:

The OP has added additional requirements:

"*In case there are `item` elements before `anothernode` and after it, then each such group of `item` elements must be enclosed in a separate `list`"*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kfollnonitem" match="item"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::item)][1])"/>

 <xsl:key name="kprecnonitem" match="item"
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[not(self::item)][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::list)]/item[1]">
  <list>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
    select="key('kprecnonitem',
                 generate-id(following-sibling::*[not(self::item)][1])
                 )"/>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(self::list) and item]/*[not(self::item)]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>

  <list>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
     select="key('kfollnonitem', generate-id())"/>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item/item[not(position()=1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is performed against he following XML document**:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <item label="c">some text</item>
        <item label="d">some text</item>
    </item>
</list>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<list>
   <item label="(1)">some text</item>
   <item label="(2)">
      <list>
         <item label="a">some text</item>
         <item label="b">some text</item>
      </list>
      <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
      <list>
         <item label="c">some text</item>
         <item label="d">some text</item>
      </list>
   </item>
</list>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 for mode solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: what happens if there are `<item>` elements both before _and after_ the `<anotherNode>`? Your solution will put them all before `<anotherNode>`. @Benjamin, what **should** happen in such cases?

Comment: @LarsH: Good observation. The desired order of siblings with other names and the list of items isn't specified. My solution preserves the relative (document) ordering between the first `item` and any non-item sibling. I think this is natural. In case another ordering is desired, it is easy to modify the solution to meet the new requirement,

Comment: If there are <item> elements before and after <anotherNode> each of these groups of <item> should have their own <list> wrapper. The order of the content should be preserved.

Comment: @Benjamin-Ortuzar and @LarsH: I have updated my answer so that the solution fulfills the latest requirements. :)

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::list)]
                          /item[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::item])]">
        <list>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                      [not(self::item)][1]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::list)]
                          /item[not(following-sibling::*[1][self::item])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <list>
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>
        </list>
    </item>
</list>
```

Also, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kItemByFirstSibling"
             match="item[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::item]]"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item
                               [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::item])][1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::list)]/item"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::list)]
                          /item[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::item])]"
                  priority="1">
        <list>
            <xsl:for-each select=".|key('kItemByFirstSibling',generate-id())">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </list>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: First stylesheet use most fine grained transversal (it will wrap any node after first `item`). Second stylesheet full recursive identity transform.

**Edit**: Addressing new requeriment, with new input, both stylesheets output:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <list>
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>
        </list>
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <list>
            <item label="c">some text</item>
            <item label="d">some text</item>
        </list>
    </item>
</list>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: see my comment to Dimitre... this works fine assuming all item elements that need to be wrapped, that are children of the same non-list element, are contiguous.

Comment: @LarsH: As I wrote in notes, first stylesheet wrap **any node** after first `item`. Second stylesheet wrap **any `item`** without `list` parent, and the relative order (between siblings) will be the relative order of the first `item`. I think this is a fair questions, but only matters if OP wants to output sibilings `list` parents.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't address this in the original question, so it may not be required. But if the input has multiple sequences of `<item>` elements that need to be wrapped, that are separated from each other by other sibling elements, e.g.:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>          
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <item label="c">some text</item>
        <item label="d">some text</item>          
    </item>
</list>
```

the earlier answers will, I believe, lump the `<item>` elements together, changing their order:

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>          
            <item label="c">some text</item>
            <item label="d">some text</item>
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
    </item>
</list>
```

Do you want that, or do you want to wrap them separately, like this?

```
<list>
    <item label="(1)">some text</item>
    <item label="(2)">
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="a">some text</item>
            <item label="b">some text</item>          
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
        <anotherNode>some text</anotherNode>
        <list> <!-- opening new wrapper node-->
            <item label="c">some text</item>
            <item label="d">some text</item>
        </list> <!-- closing new wrapper node-->
    </item>
</list>
```

If the latter, it will probably be easiest to use an XSLT 2.0 `<xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent="name()" />` construction. I don't know whether PHP 5 has XSLT 2.0 available, but if you can use such a thing, see [this good article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html).

Comment: I need the wrap them separately like on your second example.