# Rewrite XML to wrap multiple select nodes into a new one

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath

I am looking for a better solution to do the following.  Given an XML tree, e.g.

```
<root>
  <x>
    <p class="a"> </p>
    <p class="b"> </p>  <!-- Not yet wrapped, so these two <p> nodes can be wrapped, like below. -->
    <p class="b"> </p>
    <p class="a"> </p>  <!-- Not yet wrapped, so these two <p> nodes can be wrapped. -->
    <p class="a"> </p>
  </x>
  <y>
    <p class="a"> </p>
    <wrap class="b">    <!-- The <p> nodes are wrapped in a <wrap> and the attribute has moved. -->
      <p> </p>
      <p> </p>
    </wrap>
    <p class="a"> </p>
  </y>
</root>
```

I would like to select all neighboring `<p>` nodes with the same class attribute, and wrap them in a `<wrap>` element of the same class; however, don't wrap them if they are already wrapped up.

My current approach to this is to select all nodes that are candidates for wrapping:

```
candidates = xml.xpath("//*[not(self::wrap)]/p[@class]")
```

and then pick any of the candidates and accumulate all of its valid siblings into a list:

```
if len(candidates) == 0 :
    return
candidate = candidates[0] # Pick any one of the candidates.
siblings = get_siblings(candidate) # Gather all of the candidate's matching sibling elements into a list.
```

Building that sibling list is simple: given a candidate `<p>` element, iterate over all `getprevious()` elements that match (i.e. that are also `<p class="b">` elements) until I find the first one of the siblings.  Then collect all `getnext()` element into a list, resulting in a complete group of matching elements.

Once I've got that list, I create a new `<wrap>` element, copy the `class` attribute, and then add all siblings to the new element.  That done, I add that new element (with all the `<p>` siblings as its children) where the original first sibling used to be:

```
parent = candidate.getparent() # Get parent element of the candidate.
index = parent.index(candidate) # Get the index of the candidate.

wrap = lxml.etree.Element("wrap") # Create a new <wrap> element...
wrap.attrib["class"] = candidate.attrib["class"] # ...and copy the class attribute.
for s in siblings : # Iterate over all sibling elements in the list, and
    wrap.append(s) # add the sibling to the new <wrap> element, and
    del s.attrib["class"] # remove the class attribute from the sibling (because it's in the <wrap> element.
parent.insert(index, wrap) # Once all siblings are moved, add the new <wrap> element where the siblings used to be.
```

**Question**

Looking around it seems that there are better solutions to this than to implement such a rewrite manually, for example using [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)?  (I've never used it before so I'm not sure if XSLT is intended to solve such tasks.)  So: what's the "proper" way to go about this?  Are there more formal XML based tools for such rewrites/transforms, or is a manual implementation like the one above the usual way to go about this?

Comment: This question seems somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652194/wrap-group-of-xml-nodes

Answer (score 0):

are you using (c)ElementTree or lxml? They have different behaviour for the following. When 'moving' a node from one parent to another, ElementTree creates a copy, while lxml reparents the node. That behaviour might be useful for you...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from lxml import etree as lxet

e1 = et.Element('e1')
e2 = et.Element('e2')
e3 = et.SubElement(e1, 'e3')
e2.append(e3)

et.dump(e1)
<e1><e3 /></e1>
et.dump(e2)
<e2><e3 /></e2>

lxe1 = lxet.Element('e1')
lxe2 = lxet.Element('e2')
lxe3 = lxet.SubElement(lxe1, 'e3')
lxe2.append(lxe3)

lxet.dump(lxe1)
<e1/>
lxet.dump(lxe2)
<e2>
  <e3/>
</e2>
```

Comment: I'm using lxml, and thanks for the heads up!  Curious if there's another way to describe the transform, rather than manually implementing it.

Comment: couldn't simplify it much, the above does avoid some of the awkwardness of the original solution from avoiding modifying a list while iterating...